# Use an LED as an input to a phototransistor in LT-SPICE

Tags: ltspice, phototransistor

As a part of a project I am producing a light gate incorporating a photo-transistor and an LED.

The design features feedback between the the LED and photo-transistor, so it would be useful to be able to test the behavior of the circuit in SPICE.

Is there a functionality in LT-SPICE simulation to use the output of the LED as the input for a photo transistor?

Comment: Have you done any research so far into this problem?

Comment: Did you have a look how optocoupler models do it?

Comment: Someone is asking how to make an optocouple in ltspice and they are being given down thumbs.  You gotta love the intellectual pursuits and helpfulness of this "community".

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in, e.g., the 4N25 model that ships with LTSpice, the base-collector photodiode of the transistor is modelled with a voltage-controlled current source that measures the voltage drop over a resistor in series with the LED:

```
* Copyright © Linear Technology Corp. 1998, 1999, 2000.  All rights reserved.
*
.subckt 4N25 1 2 3 4 5
R1 N003 2 2
D1 1 N003 LD
G1 3 5 N003 2 .876m
C1 1 2 18p
Q1 3 5 4 [4] NP
.model LD D(Is=1e-20 Cjo=18p)
.model NP NPN(Bf=610 Vaf=140 Ikf=15m Rc=1 Cjc=19p Cje=7p Cjs=7p C2=1e-15)
.ends 4N25
```